# Pascal - произведение двузначных чисел массива

Tags: массивы, pascal

Нужно найти произведение двузначных чисел массива, сумма цифр которых кратна 6. Такие гарантированно есть.
Я написал так:

```
const N=4;  
var  
a: array[1..N] of integer;  
i,p,j:integer;  
begin  
for i:=1 to N do  
readln(a[i]);  
j:=1;  
p:=a[i] div 10; {проверяем на двузначность}  
if p div 10=0 then  
p:=p+a[i] mod 10; {считаем сумму цифр}  
if p mod 6=0 then {проверяем на кратность 6}  
j:=j*a[i]; {считаем произведение}  
Write('Proizvedenie = ',j);  
end.
```

Выводит в итоге неведомо как получившуюся херь. Где ошибка?

Comment: А Вы в цикл обработку чисел не пробовали поместить?

И, кстати, однозначные числа тоже относятся к двузначным? (в частности число 6)

Comment: @Green_Tea, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Чёрт, какая глупая ошибка! Спасибо. 
Выходит, да. =\ Как иначе можно проверить на двузначность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка на двузначность неверна. Вообще не нужно там div. Гораздо проще `a[i] >= 10 and a[i] < 100`

Считывание суммы, соответственно, тоже. `a[i] div 10 + a[i] mod 10`, где `div` целочисленное деление, `mod` остаток от деления. (синтаксис паскаля не помню, извините :-)

Comment: Понял, спасибо. 
Не поступлю я, значит, на ИТП.:(

Comment: Целочисленное деление -- div, модуль -- mod. `/` -- вещественное деление

Comment: Модуль в Паскале - abs, если я Вас правильно понял. Mod - остаток от целочисленного деления.

Comment: Да, конечно, модуль, абсолютное значение -- abs, a по модулю b (остаток от деления a на b) -- a mod b,

Comment: Тут, как я понял, при названии исходили из сравнения по модулю — http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_по_модулю

Comment: @Zelta смотрим словарь (foldoc):

        modulo operator
     
        <mathematics> (mod) The operator that returns the remainder
        after integer division of its first argument by its second.
        Written as "%" in {C} and some other languages.
     
        Where the second argument is a power of two, the result can be
        calculated much more quickly using {bitwise and} with the
        appropriate {bit-mask}.
     
        (1999-07-12)

Comment: @alexlz ну да, я знаю... А в чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Zelta видимо я неправильно понял слова

       Тут, как я понял, при названии исходили из сравнения по модулю

Решил уточнить.